# Recursive least squares in python?

Tags: python, regression, least-squares

Does anybody know a simple way to implement a recursive least squares function in Python?

I want a fast way to regress out a linear drift ([1 2 ... n], where n is the number of time points up until now) from my incoming signal every time it updates. RLS is typically what is used to do this, because the computing time does not increase as the number of time points increase.

Comment: Add examples and code that you have tried as half of those here will not be knowing as to what a *recursive least squares function* is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The least squares fit of a line to data t[], x[] is given by

```
x = xbar + (C/V)*(t-tbar)
where
xbar = Sum{ x[i]} / N
tbar = sum{ t[i]} / N
V = Sum{ (t[i]-tbar)^2 } / N
C = Sum{ (x[i]-xbar)*(t[i]-tbar) } / N
```

You can compute xbar,tbar,V and C incrementally like this:

Initially

```
N = 0
xbar = tbar = C = V = 0
```

Incorporating data t,x:

```
N += 1
f = 1.0/N
dx = x - xbar
dt = t - tbar
xbar += f*dx
tbar += f*dt
V = (1.0-f)*(V + f*dt*dt)
C = (1.0-f)*(C + f*dx*dt)
```

Note that until you have at least two data points V will be zero, and so there is no line. Note also that each x[] could be a vector; as long as xbar and C are also computed as vectors the same formulae work.

Answer (score 2):

The RLS algorithm is implemented in Python Padasip library. You can check the code on github: [Padasip source codes](https://github.com/matousc89/padasip)

Or you can use directly the library. See [documentation](http://matousc89.github.io/padasip/sources/filters/rls.html) for Padasip RLS algorithm

Answer (score 0):

see in docs [statsmodels.api.RecursiveLS(endog, exog)](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/recursive_ls.html),
try to apply with [beef.csv](https://github.com/susanli2016/Machine-Learning-with-Python/blob/master/beef.csv) or any of [statsmodels.api.datasets](https://snyk.io/advisor/python/statsmodels/functions/statsmodels.api.datasets)

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Purpose: apply Recursive Least Square (RLS) filter to investigate parameter instability.
#
# Author:  https://deepnote.com/@jayjburgess/Price-Elasticity-For-Demand-Analysis-3d47c7aa-a59a-4724-816c-72f8b270b074
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

from statsmodels.compat import lzip
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

beef = pd.read_csv('beef.csv')
print(beef.head(10))

beef_model = ols("Quantity ~ Price", data=beef).fit()
print(beef_model.summary())

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
fig = sm.graphics.plot_partregress_grid(beef_model, fig=fig)
plt.show()

beef['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(beef['Year'], format="%Y")
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *
beef['Date'] = beef.apply(lambda x:(x['Year'] + BQuarterBegin(x['Quarter'])), axis=1)
beef.drop(['Year', 'Quarter'], axis=1, inplace=True)
beef.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
beef.head(10)

endog = beef['Quantity']

# To the regressors in the dataset, we add a column of ones for an intercept
exog = sm.add_constant(beef['Price'])

# !!! >>> OP: "simple way to implement a recursive least squares function in Python"
## Recursive Least Square (RLS) filter to investigate parameter instability.
mod = sm.RecursiveLS(endog, exog)
res = mod.fit()

print(res.summary())

fig = res.plot_cusum(figsize=(10,6));
plt.show()
##In the plot above, the CUSUM statistic does not move outside of the 5% significance bands,
## so we fail to reject the null hypothesis of stable parameters at the 5% level.
```

p.s. recall [maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631498/simple-example-of-recursive-least-squares-rls)

> RLS is a special case of BLUE (best linear unbiased estimate) which
> itself is a special case of Kalman filters.